# Quickblox SDK needs login every time in Android

Tags: android, session, authentication, token, quickblox

I am trying to write a code in Android to create a basic Quickblox session using my credential. But whenever i kill the app and open the app again then the Quickblox sdk ask for signin. I am getting "Token is Required" error response.

**MyCode :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String tokenError = "No Token";
String phoneNumber = "phonenumber";
String token;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

   if (!QBChatService.isInitialized()) {
        QBChatService.init(this);

    }

    try {

        String  token = QBAuth.getSession().getToken();

        if(token!=null) {

            // Session Valid //

        } else {
            createSession();
        }

    } catch (QBResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //alertbox("Session Exception " + e.toString());

        createSession();
    }

}
 private void createSession() {

    final QBUser user = new QBUser();
    String inputUser = phoneNumber;
    user.setFullName(inputUser);
    user.setLogin(inputUser);
    user.setPassword(inputUser);


    QBAuth.createSession(user, new QBEntityCallback<QBSession>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBSession qbSession, Bundle bunde) {

            try {
                QBAuth.getBaseService().setToken(qbSession.getToken());
                QBAuth.getBaseService().setTokenExpirationDate(new Date(1443033000000L));
                tokenError = QBAuth.getBaseService().getToken();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "  " + QBAuth.getBaseService().getToken() + " :: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (BaseServiceException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                tokenError = "Error " + e.toString();
            }

            String msg = tokenError;

            alertbox(msg);

            if (tokenError.contains("Error")) {
                signIn(phoneNumber);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List<String> list) {

        }
    });
}
```

This is my above code , i am login to QuickBlox if token is null but after login i am getting the token.

But if i kill the app then the token is gone and need to login again.

It's kind of costly process from app side , so please let me know some solution , suggest me how to keep the token alive (at-least for 2hrs).

Comment: Whenever you remove your app from background you need to create session.

Comment: oh !! then whenever app will open i need to create session not signin right

Comment: Yes you need to create seesion

Comment: ok then creating session depends on network connectivity. If network is slow then the creating session also take some time. I think this process also make the app flow slow.

Comment: Yes it will take time

Comment: oh !! thanks , is there any update coming from QuickBlox to overcome this limitation.

Comment: Right now "No" , if it will i let you know. please upvote comment if you find it worth

Comment: yes thanks for your very useful response , It very worthy get an idea about my issue. But sorry i cant upvote your comment , i don't have enough points

Comment: It's okey. Whenever you find it worth just upvote it ;-)